# How to Compare Two Different Strings (string1 contains string2)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablestring, nscharacterset

I am having Two Strings:string1 and string2.
String1 contains only "ball", string2 contains "ball,fruit,doll".

Now i need to compare the string1 and string2, ball is in both the strings or not? 
and i need to remove the ball after comparing the strings. 
How to acheive this?

Comment: You don't appear to have read the documentation of `NSString`. This is a trivial problem, and you should not have asked about it **at all.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *string1 = @"ball,fruit,doll";
NSString *string2 = @"ball";
if ([string1 rangeOfString:string2].location == NSNotFound) 
{
    NSLog(@"string does not contain %@", string2);
} 
else 
{
    NSLog(@"string contains %@", string2);
}
```

Comment: You can change the names.

Comment: thanks for u r nice answer, my problem solved now.

Answer (score 1):

To compare strings you can use `isEqualToString`

To find out whether one string contains another one you can use `rangeOfString`

Take a look at the documentation of NSString, the problem is really trivial:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html